# Importing a site fron another farm; corrupt cab files

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, patching

I'm trying to import a site from one 2013 farm to another. I have all the .cmp files. when I run import-spweb in my 2013 farm, I always get an error that the "Cabinet file is corrupt."

Using FQDN/_vti_pvt/service.cnf I noticed that the site was exported from a farm with build 15.0.0.4763, mine is 15.0.0.4420.

I installed all the patches to get mine up to 4763, but it's still showing 4420. Not sure if this is my problem?

Comment: If you already installed updates and run the config wizard then right click on cab file > Check properties and make sure file is not locked....if you have access to source farm then try to run the export again and try with new files....another thing did you get only one file or multiple...if multiple then move all files.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's trace what you have did

- Your source farm build number is `15.0.4763.1000` that is **2015 October 13**
- Your destination farm build number was  `15.0.4420.1017` that is RTM.

Now you need to install the **2015 October 13** on your destination farm! to be matched and this is the correct action where the destination farm should be the same build number or higher than the source build number! For more details check [FIND FARM PATCH LEVEL / LATEST CUMULATIVE UPDATE THAT HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON SHAREPOINT FARM](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

**But**, you should be aware of applying **2015 October 13** on your destination farm requires **[SharePoint Server 2013 SP1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/04/22/sp1-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-rereleased/)** to be installed first before **2015 October 13** it's a mandatory requirement.

- So try first to install **[SharePoint Server 2013 SP1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/04/22/sp1-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-rereleased/)** then **[2015 October 13](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/10/13/october-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-is-available-for-download-2/)**
- Now try to export and import again, and check the result.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link to that article. I had already installed SP1 and 2015 October 13 updates, but didn't know I had to run the configuration wizard again for them to take affect. I now have fully-matched versions in each farm. 

However, when I run the import, I still receive a "Corrupt cabinet file" and "Failed to read package file," errors.

Comment: yes of course  you must run the config wizard after installing the patch